# How to open another xamarin forms page from clicking a item in a data template list view?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a app that has multiple xamrian forms pages. my main page consists of items in a data template list view what I need help with is when the user clicks a item in the data template list view it takes them to a different xamrian forms page here's my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SchoolTools.SchoolToolsHome">
     <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#d2d5d7">
            <Frame.Content>
              <Frame Padding="15,15,15,15"   OutlineColor="Gray" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Frame.Content>
                  <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                           FontSize="24"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </Frame.Content>
              </Frame>
            </Frame.Content>
          </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName
{
    public partial class AppName : ContentPage
    {
        public AppName()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var name = new List<Tools>
            {
                     new Tools("netitem","Internet"),
                     new Tools("emailitem","E-Mail"),
                     new Tools("mathitem","Math"),
                     new Tools("sciitem","Science"),
                     new Tools("writeitem","Handwriting"),
                     new Tools("carditem","FlashCards"),
                     new Tools("bookitem","Books"),
        };

            listView.ItemsSource = name;



            Content = listView;



        }

    }
}
```

and the tools class:

```
using System;
namespace AppName
{
    public class Tools
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string item { get; private set; }


        public Tools(string item, string name)
        {
            this.item = item;

            Name = name;



        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I Know there are many examples out there but they are only for one page I need it for multiple pages so any help would be amazing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically what I do is I handle OnItemSelected and bind the selected item to a new page. The new page is pushed onto the navigation stack.

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tools = e.SelectedItem as Tools;

    if (tools == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var toolsView = new ToolsView();
    toolsView.BindingContext = tools;
    Navigation.PushAsync(toolsView);
}
```

If the page is different for the tools:

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tools = e.SelectedItem as Tools;

    if (tools == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ContentPage page = null;

    switch (tools.Name)
    {
        case "Handwriting":
            page = new HandwritingView();
            break;
        case "Books":
            page = new BooksView();
            break;
        default:
            page = new ToolsView();
            break;
    }

    page.BindingContext = tools;
    Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer can you please go a little more in depth on OnItemSelected part based on my code? Thnaks so much :)

Comment: <ListView x:Name="listView" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">

Comment: that works but what if I want one label to go to one page and another label to go to a totally different page? thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Make a decision based on either a new PageType property you add to Tools or something else. You have the entire Tools object in the event handler.

Comment: i'm still having issues understanding what your saying can you please give me an example? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the example the only issue is when I click a label it does nothing it doesn't even look like is registering the click any idea why? Thanks again! :)

Comment: So this issue was I left out the ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" in the xaml but now it works! Thank you very much!